# How to return a word with the first letter capitalised

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
string ProperNoun::GetWord() {
    word[0] = toupper(word[0]);
    return (word);
}
```

I am having trouble trying to make it so the word that is returned from the word getter makes the first letter capitalised, if it is a propernoun, using the above code it makes the word unfindable in my dictionary, I assumed it makes the word capitalized and then searches hence I changed the word I'm searching to have a capital letter though it still wasn't finding it. My question is how can I make my code capitalise the first letter if its a propernoun.

Comment: Your run-on sentence is difficult to understand. Rephrase.

Comment: Are you aware of the notion of *local variable*?

Comment: Second Adam. More important might be the question; if you know it's a proper noun why not capitalize it if it isn't when you make the object instead of doing it every time you traverse the dictionary?

Comment: I think you should ask for feedback on your whole code over at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: At some deeper level, several things are wrong. (1) Not all proper nouns are capitalized with this simple scheme. (2) Search in a dictionary made for humans should be case-insensitive anyway (and ideally fuzzy, so that speling mistkaes are not fatal). (3) If you do want to capitalize the first letter anyway, why not do it on word construction?

Comment: You should do it in the constructor if you do it at all.

Comment: Yes, show us an example. And probably some more code (where does this 'word' come from, why/where do you want to capitalize it etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the capitalization in a second word getter to be used for display only.  This getter would not modify the stored word.

```
string ProperNoun::GetWordForDisplay() {
    string s = word;
    s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
    return s;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a second word getter for use in dictionary searches.  This getter could return a lowercase copy of the word.

```
string ProperNoun::GetWordForSearch() {
    string s = word;
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
    return s;
}
```